# Why does one of my buttons in my StackView not show? The settings are the same as a button that does show

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, button, uistackview

I have a horizontal stack view with 2 buttons. The settings for the 2 buttons are identical to my knowledge, but the button on the left does not show at all. This seems like a display issue, as *clicking* on the (invisible) button still completes the intended action.

Any thoughts as to how I can troubleshoot this or what this could be caused by? I'm quite confused as the settings in the inspector are the same for both buttons.

[image]

Comment: Try changing the background color to something like green and see if it updates.